# How can I show another view in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 action methods(a and b) and 2 views(a and b).
These action methods are having different models. Now I want to show view-b in view-a along with view-a. I don't want to use viewModel.
please help me!!

Comment: post your code. we will help you.

Comment: B should be your partial view, and needs to be placed inside view A. The controller action should load View A, and another action should load Partial View B. You need to render that action inside view A. I think that should do the stuff for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an ajax call in document.ready in view A and binded that data in a div.
This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in View A:

```
@Html.Action("ActionBName", "ActionBControllerName", new { area = string.Empty })
```

And in Controller for ViewB:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult ActionBName()
{
    // Generate ViewModel vm
    return PartialView("_NameOfViewB", vm);
}
```

`Html.Action` will run the Action method from the page to generate the html and the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute means it cannot be accessed directly, but only from a View. The View name given in the Action `return PartialView("_NameOfViewB", vm);` assumes it is located in the Controllers main View folder and has a `ViewModel` generated with a name `vm`.

Comment: What is this area=string.empty?

Comment: You can leave this out if you don't have any Areas - just use @Html.Action("ActionBName", "ActionBControllerName"). If you're using Areas, then it needs to be there to direct the Action to the correct Area.

Comment: it is showing this error System.InvalidOperationException: 'A single instance of controller "ControllerName" cannot be used to handle multiple requests. If a custom controller factory is in use, make sure that it creates a new instance of the controller for each request.'

Comment: If you're using IoC then it sounds like you've got a problem registering Controllers there

Comment: Both the Views are working fine now!! But the thing is I want them in one view only

Comment: Well if you put @Html.Action("ActionBName", "ActionBControllerName") in any View, it will get called (I thought you wanted to call it from ViewA, and you could put it in there). If you want both Views in a third View, you can just repeat the method for ViewB for ViewA and put both into a third View